# Problems with editing submitted form data before publishing

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a PHP and SQL based FAQ script that allows visitors to submit a question via a form.
The site admin can then edit the question, add an answer and publish the content to the FAQ page.

Everything is working fine except for editing the user submitted question. The input form is allowing me to edit the user submitted question and submit a provided answer, though after submission it returns the original user submitted question not the edited question.

For example, a user submits the following question:

> "What is capital of England?"

The admin can edit the question to:

> "What is the capital city of the United Kingdom?"

and the answer:

> "The capital city of the United Kingdom is London"

Though after editing and submission the edited question isn't being saved to the database and being saved as the original user submitted question:

> "What is capital of England"

Here's the code from the editfaq.php page where you can edit user submitted questions or existing questions and answers stored in the database. Editing the question or answer of an existing entry works fine, however, the user submitted question won't save.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

```
    if (isset($_GET[type]) and $_GET[type] == n) {
$get_new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ofaq_new WHERE id = $_GET[id]");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_new)) {
    $q = "$row[question]";
    $email = "$row[email]";
    $notify = "$row[notify]";
  }

  if (isset($_GET[edit])) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ofaq_qa (q, a) VALUES ('$q', '$_POST[a]')");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ofaq_new WHERE id = $_GET[id]");
    echo "$lang[publishednew].";






    if ($notify == 1) {
      $message = "$lang[mail1]\n\n$lang[question]: $q\n$lang[answer]: $_POST[a]\n\n$lang[mail2] $config[name] $lang[mail3]\n$config[faqurl]";
      $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
      $subject = "$lang[yourq] $config[name]";
      $headers = "From: $config[name] <$config[adminmail]>";

      mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
  } elseif (isset($_GET[id])) {
    echo "<b>edit user submitted question</b><p />";






    echo "<form action=faqedit.php?type=n&edit=1&id=$_GET[id] method=post>";
    echo "$lang[question]:<br />";
    echo "<input type=text name=q size=50 value='$q' /><br />";
    echo "$lang[answer]:<br />";
    echo "<textarea name=a rows=4 cols=50></textarea><br />";
    echo "<input type=submit value='$lang[pubnew]' />";
    echo "</form>";
  }
} else {
  $get_qa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ofaq_qa WHERE id = $_GET[id]");




  if (isset($_GET[id])) { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_qa)) { 
      $q = "$row[q]"; 
      $a = "$row[a]"; 
    } 




    echo "<b>edit existing question</b><p />"; 




    echo "<form action=faqedit.php?edit=1&sid=$_GET[id] method=post>"; 
    echo "$lang[question]:<br />"; 
    echo "<input type=text name=q size=30 value='$q' /><br />"; 
    echo "$lang[answer]:<br />"; 
    echo "<textarea name=a rows=4 cols=30>$a</textarea><br />"; 
    echo "<input type=submit value='$lang[editqa]' />"; 
    echo "</form>"; 

  } elseif (isset($_GET[edit])) { 
    mysql_query("UPDATE ofaq_qa set q='$_POST[q]', a='$_POST[a]' where id=$_GET[sid]"); 
    echo "$lang[written]";
  } else {
    echo "Oops... Something went horribly wrong!";
  }
}
```

---

Comment: your code is messy and if statements don't make sense. `isset($_GET[type]) and $_GET[type] == n` ??! what is `n`?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an update query, instead of deleting and reinserting ?!

And you should write this "$_GET['edit']" instead of this "$_GET[edit]" ...

---

Ok, so "$_POST['a']" contains the admin answer, but i cant see where is the variable that contains the new answer ?

In the INSERT query, your are using the "$q" variable, which contains the old question, so you're inserting the old question in the second table.

So in the admin form, try to find the new question field's name, 
if (for example) it's "newQ", so ...

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) AND $_GET['type'] == n) {
    $get_new = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ofaq_new WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id']);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_new); //You have only one record

    $q = $row['question'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $notify = $row['notify'];

    if(isset($_GET[edit])) {
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO ofaq_qa (q, a) VALUES ("$_POST[\'newQ\']", "$_POST[\'a\']")');
        mysql_query('DELETE FROM ofaq_new WHERE id = ' . $_GET[id]);

echo $lang['publishednew'] . '.';

    //ETC
```

Comment: I apologise, I'm a PHP newbie and the script is from a FAQ script I found that seemed to be abandoned by its developer in 2005! But it was the only one that did what I wanted it to do.

Comment: Thanks YOo Slim, I tried those changes and no matter what I did it just game me either blank forms or bucket loads of errors.

Comment: I ended up working out a slightly dirty workaround where I now send the contents of the user submitted question edit form to addfaq.php (the admin file used for creating new FAQ's) and added in the 'mysql_query("DELETE FROM ofaq_new WHERE id = $_GET[id]");' so as the form is submitted into the approved FAQ database it also deletes the user question from user submitted database. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's a cool little script.

### File : db.php

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $pdo_options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = "SET NAMES utf8";

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=try', 'root', '', $pdo_options);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

### File : ask.php

```
<?php
//RUNNING THE SESSION
session_start();

//Import the database connection object
require_once 'db.php';

//INIT THE ERRORS MESSAGES AS EMPTY
$serverMsg = '';

//IF THE QUESTION IS SENT
if(isset($_POST['quest']) AND isset($_POST['email'])) {
    //CHEKING IF THE DATAS ARE CORRECT
    if(empty($_POST['quest'])) $serverMsg .= '<p>Empty question.</p>';
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) $serverMsg .= '<p>Empty email.</p>';
    elseif(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $serverMsg .= '<p>Wrong email.</p>';

    //CHEKING IF THE USER DOESNT ABUSE
    if(!isset($_SESSION['quest_nbr'])) $_SESSION['quest_nbr'] = 0;

    if($_SESSION['quest_nbr'] > 2) $serverMsg .= '<p>Please wait a few minutes before asking more questions.</p>';

    //IF NO ERROR
    if(empty($serverMsg)) {
        $req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO faq (quest, email) VALUE (:q, :em)');
        $req->bindParam(':q', $_POST['quest'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $req->bindParam(':em', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $req->execute();
        $serverMsg = '<p>Question added.</p>';

        //INCREMENTING THE USER QUESTIONS
        $_SESSION['quest_nbr']++;
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <?php echo $serverMsg; ?>
    <p>Email : <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Question : <textarea name="quest"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Ask"></p>
</form>
```

### File : admin_edit.php

```
<?php
//RUNNING THE SESSION
session_start();

// CHECKING IF CURRENT USER IS AN ADMIN
// Example
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']) OR $_SESSION['admin'] == null) die('You are not allowed to be here.');

//Import the database connection object
require_once 'db.php';

//INIT THE ERRORS MESSAGES AS EMPTY
$serverMsg = '';

//IF A QUESTION IS SELECTED (to be edited)
if(isset($_GET['questId']) AND is_numeric($_GET['questId'])) {
    //IF THE NEW QUESTION AND ANSWER FORM IS SENT

    if(isset($_POST['newQuest']) AND isset($_POST['newAns'])) {
        if(empty($_POST['newQuest'])) $serverMsg .= '<p>Empty question.</p>';
        if(empty($_POST['newAns'])) $serverMsg .= '<p>Empty answer.</p>';


        //IF EVERYTHING'S OK
        if(empty($serverMsg)) {
            //CHEKING IF QUESTION REALLY EXISTS
            $req = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM faq WHERE id = :id');
            $req->bindParam(':id', $_GET['questId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $req->execute();
            $data = $req->fetch();

            //IF QUESTION EXIST, WE UPDATE IT
            if(!empty($data)) {
                $req = $db->prepare('UPDATE faq SET quest = :q, ans = :a WHERE id = :id');
                $req->bindParam(':q', $_POST['newQuest'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $req->bindParam(':a', $_POST['newAns'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $req->bindParam(':id', $_GET['questId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $req->execute();
                $serverMsg = '<p>Question edited and is visible now.</p>';

                //SENDING EN EMAIL
                $userEmail = $data['email'];
                /*

                */
            }
        }
    }

    //SHOWING THE FORM
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM faq WHERE id = :id');
    $req->bindParam(':id', $_GET['questId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $req->execute();
    $data = $req->fetch();

    echo '<form method="post" action="admin_edit.php?questId='.$_GET['questId'].'">'.$serverMsg.'
        <p>Question : <textarea name="newQuest">'.$data['quest'].'</textarea></p>
        <p>Answer : <textarea name="newAns">'.$data['ans'].'</textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Edit"></p>
    </form>';

}
else {
    // SELECTING QUESTIONS NOT ANSWERED YET
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM faq WHERE ans = ""');
    $req->execute();
    while($data = $req->fetch()) {
        echo '<a href="admin_edit.php?questId='.$data['id'].'">'.substr($data['quest'], 0, 15).' ...</a><br />';
    }
}

echo '<a href="admin_edit.php">Show questions without answer.</a>';
?>
```

### The SQL query to create the appropriate table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faq` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quest` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ans` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `quest` (`quest`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```